# Difference between os.system() and subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and http requests and I'm trying to write a script that sends http requests.
I have one main script which calls other scripts. One of those scripts looks like this

put_xml.py:

```py
# ...
# declare url and payload based on command line argument
# ...

response = requests.put(url, 
                        headers={"Content-type": "application/xml", "Accept": "application/xml"},
                        data=payload,
                        auth=("user", "pwd")
                        )
print(response.status_code)
```

When I start the script from the command line `python3 put_xml.py modulename` it works fine, when I start it from my main script with `os.system("python3 put_xml.py" + module)` it works fine but when I start it with `subprocess.Popen()` like this

```py
prozess = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "put_xml.py" , module])
prozess.communicate()
```

I get the status code 405. I've checked the parameters of `requests.put()` of all three ways and they are all the same. How do i get `subprocess.Popen()` to work with this? I'm working with the xwiki Rest Api if that's relevant.

Comment: 1. what is `module` as the paramter? 2.is this all the code, do you post something base on  envronment variables?  *declare url and payload with command line argument* --- there may be something 3. do you also use python3 when run in commandline directly?

Comment: @LeiYang 1. module is a string that tells the script which module's payload it should put. 2. no i simplified it. 3 yes im using pyhon 3 in commandline aswell

Comment: can you print the arguments `count` and each `value`? because i suspect the args has difference when invoked by two methods. `os.system` is like double click the file, maybe also `print(sys.executable)` to compare really using sam python.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, but I am sure `requests` is a red herring here.

Comment: What are `url` and `payload` under either condition? Does `module` contain spaces? Because I am pretty sure this has something to do with that.

Comment: @LeiYang i dont know what i just did differently but it seems to be working now. I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: @user3840170 can you explain why requests is a red herring?